# Eclipse - open all files in current working set?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

Is there a way to instantly open all files in the current working set?

Comment: why should we need to open all files in current working set?

Comment: just because we want to?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the open resource dialog and filter by the working set. This can be done by pressing 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Select the dropdown menu (displayed as an arrow icon) on the upper right-hand side of the "Open Resource" dialog and click on "Select Working Set...".
3. Choose the working set of interest.
4. Enter file search criteria, like `\*.*`.
5. Wait for results to return and select all files found.
6. Click the "open" button.