# Group tabs in relation to project

Tags: eclipse, grouping

When having multiple projects open in Eclipse I find it confusing not being able to distinguish between the tabs related to the associated projects.

Is it possible to group tabs in relation to what project the tabs are associated with?

Image (if anyone should doubt what tabs I mean):

[image]

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669203/can-you-save-groups-of-tabs-in-eclipse-so-you-can-open-them-later)

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for same solution, found it in Mylyn (An eclipse addon).
I have been using it for a while and feel that will also work for you.

Please visit [this tutorial link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mylyn/article.html) for head start.

Some additional info on Mylyn [(source)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/FAQ)

Mylyn is a task-focused interface for Eclipse that makes working with very large workspaces as easy as working with small ones.
Mylyn extends Eclipse with mechanisms for keeping track of the tasks that you work on.

Mylyn monitors your work activity on those tasks to identify information relevant to the task-at-hand. Mylyn monitors Eclipse and captures your interaction in a task context.
System artifacts such as files, types, methods, and fields get assigned a degree-of-interest based on how recently and frequently you interact with them.
This results in uninteresting elements being filtered from view within Eclipse, allowing you to focus in on what is important.

Comment: The majority of this answer (paragraphs 3 and 4) is lifted from the Eclipse wiki at http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/FAQ. Please edit your answer to make the source clear.